# exclude orders paid from account funds from reports - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a plugin called "Account Funds" in my wordpress site. Users can top up their account using payment gateways that I provided and the plugin adds a seperate payment gateway which users can choose during checkout and pay the amount of order from their credit.

My problem is when I look at woocommerce reports, It includes orders that are paid using account funds and also includes the account top up orders, resulting in reports like net sales being incorrect (orders paid from credit are doubled).

Is there a filter to change the way woocommerce calculates net sales and make it ignore account funds payment gateway?

Answer (score 1):

After some searching found a solution myself: add a new order status.

```
// Register New Order Statuses
function register_custom_post_statuses() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-funds-paid', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Paid with Funds', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Paid with Funds (%s)', 'Paid with Funds (%s)', 'text_domain' )
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'init', 'register_custom_post_statuses' );

// Add New Order Statuses to WooCommerce
function add_custom_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-funds-paid'] = _x( 'Paid with Funds', 'WooCommerce Order status', 'text_domain' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_statuses' );

// Set order status to "Account Funds" for orders paid with "Account Funds" gateway
function set_account_funds_order_status( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ) {
    if ( $new_status == 'completed' && $order->get_payment_method() == 'accountfunds' ) {
        $order->update_status( 'wc-funds-paid' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'set_account_funds_order_status', 10, 4 );
```

This way orders paid with account funds gateway have a seperate order status, which then can be excluded in Woocommerce > Analytics > Settings > Excluded statuses.

Comment: Sometimes own research is all it takes. Glad you sorted it.